# Magento 2 : Store Switch Problem it throws an error

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-switcher

When I try to Switch store in Front-end I got below strange error message.

> The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try
>   again.

[image]

Store redirect properly there is no issue with the redirection.
Only thing is it redirects with the above message

Note : I recenlty upgrade from M2.2.6 to M2.3.3.

Anyone face this before?
What are the step to debug or solve?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I've the same problem with a fresh 2.3.4 installation. I've different domains for each store view.